# I am not getting expected result with a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

[image][image]I am posting (Post) 2 values,  ID and 20 on next page, On next page based on these 2 values I am retrieving data from a database (Table) with while loop, within while loop I am using if/else condition, and based on result i want to update a table. I have data in 3 rows and 5 columns (two, five, ten, twenty, fifty, hundred, and five_hundred) so it should give data back in array of 3 rows, I am getting data correctly but its not looping with if/else correctly, only first 2 rows information is fine based on if/else but 3rd one not giving expected result. I want deduct 20 (post) from "twenty column" and first 2 rows values deducting properly bust last one not working within loop, I need help, I am struggling and tried many ways .. but no success!

I retrieved data and calculated with if/else condition within loop, First 2 calculation look like working but last one not calculating with retrieved value.

```
$savings_bucks = $_POST['savings_bucks'];

$busi_id = $_POST['busi_id'];

$sql5 = "SELECT two, five, ten, twenty, fifty, hundred, five_hundred FROM savingsbucks_business WHERE two IS NOT NULL AND five IS NOT NULL AND ten IS NOT NULL AND hundred IS NOT NULL AND five_hundred IS NOT NULL AND busi_id='" . $busi_id . "'";        

$result5 = mysql_query($sql5) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$numrows5 = mysql_num_rows($result5);

    while ($row5 = @mysql_fetch_array($result5, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $sbb_id = $row5['sbb_id'];
        $twos = $row5['0'];
        $fives = $row5['1'];
        $tens = $row5['2'];
        $twentys = $row5['3'];
        $fiftys = $row5['4'];
        $hundreds = $row5['5'];
        $five_hundreds = $row5['6'];


    if ($savings_bucks == "2"){
    echo "Its Two".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $twos=$twos-$savings_bucks;


    } elseif ($savings_bucks == "5"){
    echo "Its Five".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $fives=$fives-$savings_bucks;


    } elseif ($savings_bucks == "10"){
    echo "Its Ten".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $tens=$tens-$savings_bucks;


    } elseif ($savings_bucks == "20"){
    echo "Its Twenty".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $twentys=$twentys-$savings_bucks;


    } elseif($savings_bucks == "50") {
    echo "Its fifty".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $fiftys=$fiftys-$savings_bucks;


    } elseif ($savings_bucks == "100"){
    echo "Its Hundred".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $hundreds=$hundreds-$savings_bucks;


    } elseif ($savings_bucks == "500"){
    echo "Its Five Hundred".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $five_hundreds=$five_hundreds-$savings_bucks;


    } 
    }
```

I am expecting after running while loop, It must only select those rows which have value, and then deduct posted value (for ex: 20)

if i have 20 in middle row of column twenty, and posted value is 20,  result  should be 0, and if 2 rows have 20 in each row of column twenty, then both result should be 0 or if all 3 rows have 20 in each row of column twenty then all three result should be 0

I tried to explain...

Comment: @Nick, any help ?

Comment: I have added a image with explanation what i want to achieve.

Comment: @Dharman, Thanks, I have plan for it, once project will be completed, I will update it!, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
$savings_bucks = $_POST['savings_bucks'];

$busi_id = $_POST['busi_id'];

$sql5 = "SELECT two, five, ten, twenty, fifty, hundred, five_hundred FROM savingsbucks_business WHERE two IS NOT NULL AND five IS NOT NULL AND ten IS NOT NULL AND hundred IS NOT NULL AND five_hundred IS NOT NULL AND busi_id='" . $busi_id . "'";        

$result5 = mysql_query($sql5) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$numrows5 = mysql_num_rows($result5);

    while ($row5 = @mysql_fetch_array($result5, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $sbb_id = $row5['sbb_id'];
        $twos = $row5['0'];
        $fives = $row5['1'];
        $tens = $row5['2'];
        $twentys = $row5['3'];
        $fiftys = $row5['4'];
        $hundreds = $row5['5'];
        $five_hundreds = $row5['6'];


    switch ($savings_bucks){
    case "2":
    echo "Its Two".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $twos=$twos-$savings_bucks;
     break;

    case "5":
    echo "Its Five".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $fives=$fives-$savings_bucks;
    break;

    case "10":
    echo "Its Ten".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $tens=$tens-$savings_bucks;
    break;

    case "20":
    echo "Its Twenty".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $twentys=$twentys-$savings_bucks;
    break;

   case "50":
    echo "Its fifty".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $fiftys=$fiftys-$savings_bucks;
    break;

    case "100":
    echo "Its Hundred".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $hundreds=$hundreds-$savings_bucks;
    break;

    case "500":
    echo "Its Five Hundred".$savings_bucks."<br>";
    $five_hundreds=$five_hundreds-$savings_bucks;
    break;

    } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Otávio Barreto, Its working same as It was with if/else, Its still counting blank rows and wherever blank rows coming its deduct from that row too, so blank row gives minus(-) value, If i post 20, and in that column if 2 rows are blank, its showing -20 for that rows, I have added a image/photo with explanation.. Thanks!

Comment: Reformulate your database instead of multiple columns named 10 ,2 etc, add a single column named what ever you think , like:  number its returning blank rows because its on multiple columns, add only a single one and post the image, After that i Will reformulate My answer.

Comment: OK, any suggestion,  how it should be ?

Comment: something like `sbb_id,  consu_id, busi_id , type, number_bucks, todayDate, todayTime`

Comment: I have added another image to more clarify, may be this way you can give better answer/help!, I am already have done too much work, now making changes in tables, I need again work from scratch...Thanks!

Comment: Did you changed the table columns as i told you? You dont need multiples columns with each value, you only need a single column to store 5,20 etc, and than i can filter by SQL query the value, thats why you are getting blank results because It loads ALL columns when It really should need only one.